# How to print UTF-8 encoded text to the console in Julia?

Tags: encoding, visual-studio-code, julia

I use the code-runner plug-in for VSCode under Chinese version of Windows and the output of Julia command is garbled like many other language.

I found solution of Python by `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && python`. How to make Julia command to output with utf-8 encoding under Windows?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?